# Registering a signal handler in Haskell with an action depending on state

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monad-transformers

I have some function `app :: StateT AppState IO ()` which maintains some application state whilst doing a bunch of computation and IO (I have defined `main = void $ runStateT app initialState`). I want to register a signal handler `handler :: StateT AppState IO ()` which can look at and modify the current state by writing something like

```
installHandler sigINT (Catch handler) Nothing
```

This does not work because `Catch :: IO () -> Handler` and `handler :: StateT AppState IO ()`.

I have tried the following:

```
installHandler . Catch . pure <$> handler <*> pure Nothing
```

This runs `handler` the instant this line of code is evaluated (since we are using the `StateT` applicative). Moreover, `Catch . pure <$> handler` is the same as `Catch . pure $ ()` since we run the side effects to retrieve `()`, then applying `pure` just wraps this up in `IO` without capturing those side effects.

Is there a way I can register the signal handler so that it actually does stuff without breaking the abstraction of `StateT`? I would appreciate any advice!

Also, sorry if I have ruffled any feathers by using the phrase "side effects".

Comment: I don't think this is doable. In a handler, or any other `IO` action, you can only modify the state pointed-to by a `IORef` (roughly). The state in the external layer `StateT AppState` is not accessible there. If the handler only needs to modify a small part of `AppState`, you could put that part behind a `IORef`, and keep a (constant!) ref to that inside `AppState`. (You could even add a further `ReaderT (IORef ...)` layer to the monad stack). That will make it a bit cumbersome to access that part of the state, but it looks doable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per @chi's comment, there's no way to get this exact design to work.

Signals are handled via a separate IO thread, so the most straightforward way of implementing this is via a shared mutable reference that is "known" to the application monad and provided via a closure to the handler function.

If the handler only needs to access a tiny part of the state, and that tiny part isn't used much throughout the rest of the application, then the easiest approach will be to add a field to the application state to store either an `IORef` or an `MVar` to that tiny piece of state.

In particular, if you're just trying to set a flag in the handler that will be "noticed" in an application loop, an `IORef` will be fine.  The following program illustrates the general approach:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedRecordDot #-}

import System.Posix.Signals
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.IORef

data AppState = AppState
  { count :: Int
  , flagINT :: IORef Bool
  }

app :: StateT AppState IO ()
app = do
  x <- gets count
  modify $ \s -> s{count=s.count+1}
  liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Running " ++ show x
  liftIO $ threadDelay 1000000
  quit <- gets flagINT >>= liftIO . readIORef
  if quit then do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Quitting"
    else app

main = do
  flagINT_ <- newIORef False
  installHandler sigINT (Catch (writeIORef flagINT_ True)) Nothing
  runStateT app (AppState 0 flagINT_)
```

Here, I've installed the handler in `main` where I directly access the `flagInt_` mutable reference that's created there.  Alternatively, you can set the handler in the application monad by reading the flag reference from the state:

```
setINTHandler :: StateT AppState IO ()
setINTHandler = do
  flagINT_ <- gets flagINT
  liftIO $ installHandler sigINT (Catch (writeIORef flagINT_ True)) Nothing
  pure ()
```

A few things to note:

- Even though `flagInt` is a field of a mutable `State`, this is only for convenience.  `flagInt` is just accessed as a read-only only field that gives the mutable reference for the actual mutable flag.  It could just as well be part of a separate `Reader`.
- The use of an `IORef` here and non-atomic `writeIORef` is sufficiently thread-safe for this particular example.  If you're performing a more complicated manipulation of the state within the handler), then you may need to be a little more careful and maybe switch to using an `MVar`.

If, as you seem to be suggesting in your question, you want to perform a fairly complex manipulation of the state from the handler, then you need to rewrite your program with a concurrency-safe explicit state.  A monadic `State` won't work well for this.  For performance reasons, you can't be locking and unlocking the state for every monadic operation.  Instead, you'll need to operate in the `IO` monad and manipulate the state more explicitly.

Note that a reasonable design for this might be to use an application monad of the form:

```
app :: ReaderT (MVar AppState) IO ()
```

where you `takeMVar` and `putMVar` the state over chunks of main application code.  When the handler is invoked, it will wait on the next main application `putMVar` before performing its manipulation.